# How can I avoid printing anything in Bash `printf` with an empty array?

Tags: arrays, bash, printf

I often print out the contents of an array using a quick `printf` shorthand like this:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${my_array[@]}"
$ printf "%s\0" "${my_array[@]}"
```

This works great in general:

```
$ my_array=(limburger stilton wensleydale)
$ printf "%s\n" "${my_array[@]}"
limburger
stilton
wensleydale
$
```

Works great, but when the array is empty it still outputs a single character (a newline or null byte):

```
$ my_array=()
$ printf "%s\n" "${my_array[@]}"

$
```

Of course, I can avoid that by testing first for an empty array:

```
$ [[ ${#my_array[@]} -gt 0 ]] && printf "%s\n" "${my_array[@]}"
$ (( ${#my_array[@]} )) && printf "%s\n" "${my_array[@]}"
```

But I use this idiom all the time and would prefer to keep it as short as possible. Is there a better (shorter) solution, maybe a different `printf` format, that won't print anything at all with an empty array?

Comment: It seems like the root problem is that `printf` fills in missing arguments. For example, with a quote spec, it prints the empty string: `printf '%q\n'` -> `''`; and with a number spec, it prints zero: `printf '%d\n'` -> `0` or `printf '%d %d\n' 5` -> `5 0`.

Comment: `(( ${#my_array[@]} ))`  fails in a `set -e` context. Instead, you may want the equivalent:
`(( ${#my_array[@]} == 0 )) || printf "%s\n" "${my_array[@]}"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash's parameter expansion might help:

```
printf "%b" "${my_array[@]/%/\\n}"
```

From `help printf`:

> `%b`: expand backslash escape sequences in the corresponding argument

or

```
printf "%s" "${my_array[@]/%/$'\n'}"
```

Answer (score 4):

For what it is worth:

```sh
(( ${#my_array[@]} )) && printf "%s\n" "${my_array[@]}"
```

`(( ${#my_array[@]} ))` is a Bash's stand-alone arithmetic expression that evaluates to `true` when array length is greater than 0.

Anyway, when I need to debug the content of an array. I prefer to use:

```sh
declare -p my_array
```

It will clearly show details that a simple `printf '%s\n'` cannot, like:

- element key or index,
- empty elements,
- elements containing non-printable characters,
- all of variable type or flags,
- if array is undeclared, void `declare -a my_array=` or empty `declare -a my_array=()`.

Comment: +1 for `declare -p`! I thought of it myself but neglected to mention it :) For `(( ${#my_array[@]} ))`, though, OP has tried it already.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, a plain old for-loop works like you want. It's not shorter, but it is more obvious, so this is what I'd use for scripts instead of a shorthand.

```
$ my_array=(limburger stilton wensleydale)
$ for i in "${my_array[@]}"; do printf '%s\n' "$i"; done
limburger
stilton
wensleydale
$ my_array=()
$ for i in "${my_array[@]}"; do printf '%s\n' "$i"; done
$
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no better solution than to test if the array is not empty.